# Argument-dependent lookup through base of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, argument-dependent-lookup

I have a template class `NB::B<T>` derived from a non-template class `NA::A` in a namespace. `act<T>` is a template function calling `add_ref` function on an instance of its template argument. Specifically, `act<NB::B<int>>` wants to find `add_ref` defined in the namespace of `NB::B`'s base using ADL. The complete example is following:

```
template<class T>
void act() {
  T* p = 0;
  add_ref(p); // the failing line
}

namespace NA
{
  struct A { };

  // I want ADL to find this:
  void add_ref(A* p) {
  }
}

namespace NB
{
  // template class with non-template base
  template <class T>
  struct B: NA::A { };

  typedef B<int> Bi;

  // using NA::add_ref; // fixes the problem
}

int main()
{
  act<NB::Bi>();
}
```

This compiles okay in `gcc` (4.7.0). And in `Comeau` online. However `clang` (3.1) fails:

```
a.cpp:4:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'add_ref'
```

At the same time, the standard reads:

> 3.4.2/2 …
>
> — If T is a template-id, its associated namespaces and classes are the namespace in which the template is defined; for member templates, the member template’s class; the namespaces and classes associated with the types of the template arguments provided for template type parameters (excluding template template parameters); the namespaces in which any template template arguments are defined; and the classes in which any member templates used as template template arguments are defined.

Surprisingly, template's bases aren't listed as paths to associated namespaces. Thus `clang`'s behavior appears to be correct. And `Comeau` and `gcc` are accepting incorrect program.

At the same time, `3.4.2/3` states that `using`'s in argument's namespaces have no effect:

> When considering an associated namespace, the lookup is the same as the lookup performed when the associated namespace is used as a qualifier (3.4.3.2) except that:
>
> — Any using-directives in the associated namespace are ignored.

But when I uncomment the `using NA::add_ref` line `clang` is happy to compile the test.

To put my example into practical perspective, you can think that `act` was a method of `boost::intrusive_ptr`, `add_ref(A*)` was `intrusive_ptr_add_ref(CBase*)` and `B` was some template, deriving from base `CBase`.

Regarding this I have several questions:

1. Am I right that `clang`'s is correct rejecting my test program, and `gcc` and `Comeau` don't follow the standard?
2. Is there a reason why the standard specifies such an impractical behavior (disallows template class bases as associated namespaces)?
3. Is `clang` wrong accepting my test program with the `using NA::add_ref` directive on the grounds of `3.4.2/3`?
4. Should I report a bug? :)

P.S. I have read [clang Language Compatibility FAQ](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html) and didn't find an answer there.

Comment: Does C++11 mode help? C++11 seems to have clarified the wording, since in fact `NB::B<int>` is a class (that happens to be a template specialization), not a template. (The rules, IIUC, are that the namespaces associated with the template of which the type is a specialization are *added* to the namespaces associated to the class.)

Comment: Isn't this going to be very fragile? At some point you probably add a default implementation of `add_ref` which will always be a better match than the associated namespace of the direct base?

Comment: @LucDanton, you are right. Both points (about `class`'s and `template-id`'s associated namespaces) apply to class `template-id`'s.

Comment: @pmr, this is indeed kind of fragile. Though I didn't understand your comment. Nothing is going to be found without ADL because no `add_ref` functions are at the scope of the call from `intrusive_ptr.hpp`.

Comment: @NichtVerstehen With default implementation I meant: unless there is a function `add_ref` in the scope of your `act` function. The template in the namespace of `act()` can be a better match and will be chosen instead of the function associated with the base.

Comment: Regarding point 3, `using NA::add_ref;` is not a using-directive, it is a using-declaration, so 3.4.2/3 does not apply. A using-directive looks like `using namespace NA;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From n3337, which is basically C++11 with minor editorial changes, the 3.4.2/2 reads:

> For each argument type T in the function call [...] The sets of
>   namespaces and classes are determined in the following way: [...]
>
> - If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and **its direct and indirect base classes**. Its associated namespaces are the namespaces of which its associated classes are members. **Furthermore**, if T is a class template specialization, ...

And it then continues with basically the same quote you posted in the question. The important difference here is the **furthermore**, which means that the list that you quoted (and I omitted) is in addition to the already mentioned namespaces, and that includes the namespaces of which the base class is a member.

1. Gcc and comeau are right, and clang++ is wrong in rejecting the code.
2. < does not apply >
3. Clang++ is wrong in rejecting it without the `using NA::add_ref`.
4. <strike>Yes, you should probably report a bug.</strike> It seems that it has already been reported and fixed.

Comment: he bug was already reported some time ago and fixed. zhr bug was thag clang did not inatantiate the template to find its base classes (and its friend declarations)

Comment: Thanks, @david-rodriguez-dribeas. That 'furthermore' clarifies the issue.

Comment: @johannes-schaub-litb, Any chance you remember a link to the bug you are talking about? I just checked this on a fresh build of `clang` trunk and the bug is still present.